# How to write a subscript in the line of a fraction?

Tags: subscripts

Consider a fraction. I would like to write a subscript at the end of the line of the fraction. Something like the following

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Well, I haven't tried anything since I have no clue of what to try. It would be very helpful to have a sort of online graphic editor (like GIMP or similar) where to draw the idea. But there isn't and I do not know if I can post figures or the likes in the question.

Comment: @JuanI.Perotti You can upload PNG or JPEG pictures through the interface (click on the “mountain” icon above the edit window). If the image is not added because of your still low reputation, a user with sufficient privilege will add it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the info. I just uploaded a plot with the idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a subscript to an empty item after the fraction; the numerator and denominator should be made a bit wider, in order not to confuse the subscript as a superscript to the denominator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subscriptedfrac}[3]{%
  \frac{\,#1\,}{\,#2\,}{}_{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\subscriptedfrac{a}{b}{c}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]